# Factorial quotient with same number of factors

Tags: limits, factorial

I have this limit:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{n!(3n)!}{((2n)!)^2}$$

How can I evaluate this? I know that the answer is $+\infty$

Comment: it must be $n\to \infty$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$
\frac{(3n)!}{(2n)!} = \frac{(3n)(3n-1)(3n-2)...}{(2n)(2n-1)(2n-2)...} = (3n)(3n-1)(3n-2)...(2n+2)(2n+1) 
$$
and similarly
$$
\frac{(2n)!}{n!} = \frac{(2n)(2n-1)(2n-2)...}{(n)(n-1)(n-2)...} = (2n)(2n-1)(2n-2)...(n+2)(n+1).
$$
So
$$
\frac{n!(3n)!}{(2n)!(2n)!} = \frac{(3n)(3n-1)(3n-2)...(2n+2)(2n+1) }{(2n)(2n-1)(2n-2)...(n+2)(n+1)}\ge \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^n,
$$
which is unbounded.

Comment: Thank you! This is the answer I'm looking for

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) $n! \approx n^ne^{-n}\sqrt{2 \pi n}$.  Plug that in and see what happens to the numeric factors.  All the $n$s will disappear, as will the $e$s

Comment: How can I use it for (2n)! and (3n)! ?

Comment: Plug them in.  $(2n)! \approx (2n)^{(2n)}e^{-2n}\sqrt{2\pi (2n)}$

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

One way is to cancel the terms:
$$
\frac{n! (3n)!}{(2n)!^2}
 = \frac{\prod_{k=1}^n k \times \prod_{k=1}^{3n} k}
        {\prod_{k=1}^{2n} k^2}
 = \frac{(2n+1) \times \ldots \times 3n}
        {(n+1) \times \ldots \times 2n}
 = \prod_{k=1}^n \frac{2n+k}{n+k}
 = \prod_{k=1}^n \left(1 + \frac{n}{n+k}\right)
$$
so each product term is actually above one, and later ones are closer to $1.5$, and the number of such terms increases without bound as $n \to \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

As an inductive step, for $n\ge1$,
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{n!(3n)!}{(2n)!^2}
&=\frac{n\,3n(3n-1)(3n-2)}{2n(2n-1)\,2n(2n-1)}\frac{(n-1)!(3n-3)!}{(2n-2)!^2}\\
&=\frac{27}{16}\frac{\left(1-\frac1{3n}\right)\left(1-\frac2{3n}\right)}{\left(1-\frac1{2n}\right)\left(1-\frac1{2n}\right)}\frac{(n-1)!(3n-3)!}{(2n-2)!^2}\\
&=\frac{27}{16}\frac{1-\frac1n+\frac2{9n^2}}{1-\frac1n+\frac1{4n^2}}\frac{(n-1)!(3n-3)!}{(2n-2)!^2}\\
&\ge\frac32\frac{(n-1)!(3n-3)!}{(2n-2)!^2}
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Interesting is the case of
$$A_n=\frac{(a n)!\, (b n)!}{\left(\left(\frac{a+b}{2} n \right)!\right)^2}$$ Using three times Stirling approximation
$$\log(A_n)= \left(a \log (a)+b \log (b)-(a+b) \log \left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)\right) n+\log \left(\frac{2 \sqrt{a b}}{a+b}\right)+O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$$